# How to print the multiple html element in jquery html() function?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

How to print the multiple array values in jquery html() function?

```
    $('#mer').click( function() {

      var checked = [];
      var attr = [];
      var attr0 = [];
      var unchecked = [];  
     //$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
     $('input:checkbox[name="attr[]"]').each(function(){

        //attr.push($(this).next("label").text());
        if( this.checked ){
          checked.push(this);
          attr.push($(this).next("label").text());

        } else{
          unchecked.push(this);
          attr0.push($(this).next("label").text());
        }
      });

        //checked check box show
        for (j=0; j < checked.length; j++)
          {
            //alert(checked[j]);
            $('#ch').append($('<li>').html(checked[j]+attr[j]);
          }

        //unchecked check box show
        for (j=0; j < unchecked.length; j++)
          {
            //alert(checked[j]);
            $('#ch').append($('<li>').html(unchecked[j]+attr0[j]);
          }

       $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('disabled', true);  
       $('.checklist').hide();
       $('#ch').show();   
    });
```

Comment: for a one dimentional array you can simply use `.join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code does all that you want:

```
$('#mer').click( function() {       
   $(':checkbox[name="attr[]"]:checked').add(':checkbox[name="attr[]"]:not(:checked)').each(function(){
      var text = $(this).next("label").text();
      $('#ch').append($('<li/>').append($(this).clone()).append(text));
   });
   $(':checkbox:checked').attr('disabled', true);  
   $('.checklist').hide();
   $('#ch').show();   
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers